# if one string or another string equals third string

Tags: php, string, compare

I have been racking my brain for a bit and getting nowhere.  I'm probably missing something really simple, but what I effectively need is.

if string 1 or 2 is set then compare with string 3 providing string 3 is not null.

```
if($_SESSION['code'] || $_GET['id'] <> $_POST['code'] && isset($_POST['code']))
```

Comment: What are you comparing to string 3?  Also, what are you doing with the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow, but you're logic seems to state:

```
if(isset($string3)){
    if(isset($string1)){
         strcmp($string1,$string3);
    }elseif(isset($string2)){
         strcmp($string2,$string3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it to be all in the same if statement if possible.

Comment: if you're looking to do a different strcmp based on the conditions, you couldn't technically have everything within a single if.  If you're looking to just have everything on the same line, you could go ternary.  i.e.   $res = (isset($string3))? (isset($string1))?strcmp($string1,$string3):strcmp($string2,$string3): null;

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($string3) && ((isset($string1) && $string1 == $string3) || (isset($string2) && $string2 == $string3)))
```

Something like this would work. First see if isset $string3. Then a wrapped or operator individually checking isset $string1 or 2 and if they equal string 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ($a = $_SESSION['code'] ? $_SESSION['code'] : $_GET['id'])
 && isset($_POST['code']) && $a == $_POST['code']) {
```

If you want `$_GET['id']` to override `$_SESSION['code']` in the case that both are set:

```
if( ($a = $_GET['id'] ? $_GET['id'] : $_SESSION['code'])
 && isset($_POST['code']) && $a == $_POST['code']) {
```

More correctly:

```
if( (isset($_SESSION['code']) || isset($_GET['id']))
 && ($a = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : $_SESSION['code'])
 && isset($_POST['code']) && $a == $_POST['code']) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((!empty($_POST['code']) || !empty($_SESSION['code'])) && $_GET['id']<>$_POST['code']){
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer would be good, not only a line of code. See [FAQ item 9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/138309)

Answer (score 0):

This could be

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['code']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_POST['code'])
    ($_SESSION['code'] == $_POST['code'] || $_GET['id'] == $_POST['code']))
```

This means all the variables must be set and have value then it compares if the $_SESSION['code'] or $_GET['id'] is equal with the $_POST['code']